# What are the significances of reading Sundara Kanda (सुन्दरकाण्ड)?

Tags: ramayana

In addition to the aforementioned question, I would also like to know the proper procedure & time to recite or read the same.

Comment: When in difficult times It gives a brave heart and a sense of sustained purpose with Bhakthi  in your work the day following... like Hanuman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well basically Sunderkand sings the praises of Shri Ram. Whoever hears it with devotion shall without any means be able to cross the ocean of life. As stated [here](https://www.astroyogi.com/articles/astrologyarticles/get-rid-of-negativity-and-hurdles-by-reciting-sunderkand.aspx):

> Sunderkand is a chapter from the Ramcharitmanas which is written by
>   the revered poet Goswami Tulsidas. It is one of the seven kands
>   (sections) of what constitutes the epic Ramayana and it is believed
>   that reciting Sunderkand on a regular basis can help ward off evils,
>   remove obstacles in path and bestows one with happiness and
>   prosperity. Sunderkand is one such text that mentions about a
>   devotee’s victory. It highlights how Lord Hanuman crossed the ocean
>   and survived the obstacles during his journey to Lanka to find Sita
>   Maa. Since Lord Hanuman was successful in his mission to gather
>   information about Sita, this chapter also depicts the wisdom and
>   vigour of Lord Hanuman. Sunderkand also mentions a few significant
>   life lessons. In Sunderkand, Lord says “Nirmal Man Jan So Mohe Paava,
>   Mohe Kapat Chhal Chidra Na Bhaava,” which means that like himself, the
>   Lord also likes those devotees who have a pure mind and noble
>   thoughts.

Reciting Sunderkand does not only offer mental peace but also gives one the strength and determination to carry out their tasks. It can help you get rid of all your problems, grant your wishes and protect you from the malefic effects of unfavorable planetary positions. By reciting the verse given below daily, you can get relief from your sufferings.

**Ten ways of getting maximum benefits from Sunderkand** as described [here](http://www.sunderkandsatsangsamuh.org/benefits.asp):

> Sunderkand can be done any time, any day with or without music.
>   However following will help one to get maximum advantage.
>
> - If you are doing alone it is better you do it early morning around 4-6 in "Bhrahm Mahurat".
> - A group Sunderkand can be done any time but gives maximum benefit when done after 7pm in the evening.
> - Sunderkand done in a group with music is Ideal.
> - Sunderkand done in group with music around 5 am on Tuesday, Saturday, on full moon day and no moon day is the ultimate for getting
>     benefits.
> - While doing Sunderkand one should not get up at the same time phone should be switched off, no break or no intra or inter talking.
> - Sunderkand done after understanding the meaning of the verses mentioned therein gives instant result.
> - Before commencing Sunderkand one should take bath and wear light colored clothes.
> - Sunderkand should be done with empty stomach and fasting on Saturdays or Tuesday gives maximum benefit.
> - Sunderkand necessarily be started by 'AAHAVAN' ('invitation' verses of shri Hanumanji) and ended by "BIDAI".
> - In order to get better concentration during Sunderkand, do not leave your eyes away from the book. If you do not require a book than close
>     your eyes and imagine the Pratima of Shri Hanumanji.

Answer (score 3):

As per Hindupedia.com, those who are unable to recite the whole Sundara kanda from Valmiki's Ramayana, can instead recite a shorter version of it called the **Samkshepa Sundarakanda**. This text is found in the Vayu Purana.

You can read it from [this page](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Samkshepa_Sundara_kandam).

From the introduction, we find:

> **Those who do not have time to read the entire Ramayana, could get the
>   same effect by reading Sundara Kanda. People who do not have even time
>   to read full Sundara Kanda, Could read this “Samkshepa Sundara Kanda
>   (Sundara Kanda in brief) and be benefited.** It is written that reading
>   this would cure illnesses, give long life, bring to an end enmity, and
>   lead to all round happiness and well being.

So, the benefits of reciting the Sundara Kanda of Valmiki's Ramayana is said to be obtained by reciting this shorter version from the Vayu Purana.

So, we can now just check what the Phalasruti of this Samkshepa Sundarakanda is to know what the Phalasruti will be of the longer version.

And, here's the Phalasruti of the Samkshepa Sundarakanda:

> Ayushyam arogya karam yasayam soubrathrukam budhikaram shubham
>   cha,
>  Srothawya methan niyamena sadbirakhyana mojaskaram rhidhi
>   kaamai., 36
>
> **This story increases life and health, Makes one famous and increases
>   love among brothers, Makes one wise and brings all good things, And
>   also fulfills all wishes. If heard with discipline and devotion.**
>
> Swasthi prajabhya paripalayantham,
>  Nyayena margena mahim maheesa,
>   Gobrahmanabhya shubamasthu nithyam,
>  Loka samastha sukhino
>   bhavanthu., 37
>
> Let all people live happily, Let kings rule with justice, Let cows and
>   Brahmins live happily, And let all the people of this earth live
>   happily for ever.
>
> Ramaya Ramabhadraya Ramachandraya Vedhase,
>  Raghunadhaya Nadhaya
>   Sithaya pathaye nama., 38
>
> My salutations to Lord Rama, To Ramabadhra, to Ramachandra, To the
>   lord of Vedas, To the chief of Raghu clan, To the lord of the world,
>   And to the Lord of Sita.
>
> Kayenavacha Manasendryrva budhyatmanava prakrithai swabhawat,
>   Karomi yadyat sakalam parasmai narayanayethi samarpayami., 39
>
> I offer all that I do, To Lord Narayana, Whatever I do with my body,
>   Whatever I do with my mind, Whatever I do with my brain, Whatever I do
>   with my soul, And whatever I do with nature’s help
>
> Asadhya sadhaka swamin asadhyam thava kim vada,
>  Rama dhootha daya
>   sindho math karya sadhaya prabho., 40
>
> Hey,emissary of Rama, Who is the ocean of mercy, And who does the
>   impossible, Is there some thing impossible for you? So please help me
>   to complete my duties.